# Stuck In For Loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, infinite, 2d-games

Okay so, I added saving into my game (through serialization), which works completely fine, but these items have things like sprites and stuff that I logically wouldn't save, how I got around that was pretty simple.

I made a method in my Item class (every item extends it) that assigns everything it needs to (called basicInitialization()). This works great!

However, I noticed that any code placed after the loading of items wouldn't run. I investigated and realized I was stuck in an infinite for-loop:

```
public void loadItems(Player p) {
        Item[] temp = SaveGame.loadItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            this.removeByIndex(i);  
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
            items[j] = temp[j];
        }
        for (int t = 0; t < items.length; t++) {

            if (items[t] == null) {
                t += 1;
            } 


            items[t].basicInitialization();

            if (items[t] instanceof EquipableItem) {
                items[t].basicInitialization(((EquipableItem)items[t]).slot);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I removed the:

```
items[t].basicInitialization();

if (items[t] instanceof EquipableItem) {
    items[t].basicInitialization(((EquipableItem)temp[t]).slot);                
}
```

portion and the problem went away.

Am I missing something really obvious here?
Thanks for any help you can give, if anymore code is needed I will happily give it!

Edit:
 - Re-structured some code
Here is an example of basicInitialization:

```
 public void basicInitialization() {
            this.sprite = Sprite.HealthPotion;
            this.name = "Health Potion";
            this.value = "25";
            this.desc = "Heals Up to 5 HP";
            level = Game.getGame().getLevel();
        }
```

Comment: Show us `basicInitialization()`? Does it call `loadItems()`?

Comment: Nope, added an example for a health potion in the original post.

Comment: And you're sure it's an I fine loop, not an exception or a call taking a long time? If you put a println in the loop, it'll print out over and over? What happens if you take out only one of the basicInitialization calls?

Comment: One thing that I notice is that your instanceof check is on `items[i]`, but you then cast `temp[i]`. So I'm wondering if there's a ClassCastException that later gets swallowed and ignored.

Comment: They don't print over and over, I don't get any exceptions, and I'm not sure about a call taking a long time. I also created an empty method and called the empty one instead of basicInitialization and it did the same thing. I need to take out both for it to continue, and I updated the code in the original post again where I got rid of the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the code inside first `for` loop as :

```
int j = 0;
if (temp[i] == null) { //If there is no item then continue to the next one
    i+= 1
}
else{
    items[j] = temp[i];
    j++;
}
```

If the next item is null, then it would get assigned without the `else` block.

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't complete and now when there is a gap in array 

item 1, null, item 2

item 2 doesn't get initialized

Comment: Maintain the items' array index separately with `j`. Will edit the answer.

Comment: Where are you setting
    j = 0;
outside the for-loop?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still never completes. I also updated the original post with code that seems to work better, but it still doesn't using the old or 'new' version.

Comment: Can I get your opinion on this: What if I get the last item in the list and then say if the current increment is equal to the last item, then return?

Comment: the value of j after the loop will be the size of the items list. And j-1 will be the last index.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've finally fixed it, thanks for all the help! It was definitely a tough nut to crack!

```
 public void loadItems(Player p) {

      Item[] temp = SaveGame.loadItems();


      for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       this.removeByIndex(i);  // Remove all current items
      }

      if (this.lastItemInList(temp) == -1) { // If the loaded item list has no items
       return;
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
       items[j] = temp[j];items
      }
      for (int t = 0; t < items.length; t++) { 
       if (items[t] == null) {
        if (t != items.length) {
         for (int i = t; i < items.length; i++) {
          if (items[i] != null) {
          t = i;       //Gets the next time there is an item that isn't null
          break;
          }
         }




        }
       } 

       items[t].basicInitialization();

       if (items[t] instanceof EquipableItem) {
        items[t].basicInitialization(((EquipableItem)items[t]).slot);
       }

       if (t == this.lastItemInList(items)) { //Once it hits the last item, then return
        System.out.println(":::FULLY LOADED ITEMS >> RETURNING:::");
        return;
       }
      }
     }
```